# Icons in jQuery UI dialog title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the code below to create a jQuery dialog box. By default there is a close icon on title bar, but I want to add some of the other icons in title bar as well for different functionality.

The code used for the dialog box is:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Dialog Title",
        height: 400,
        width: 500
    });
});
```

I'm using following .css and .js files:

```
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 38):

You can define HTML in the `title` option when creating the dialog box. Therefore, using the existing jQuery UI icon sprites, we can use this Javascript:

---

#### For jQuery UI 1.10.0

You need to override the undocumented `_title` function, according to [Bug #6016](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6016) to ensure that the `title` attribute is not escaped.

```
var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog();

dialog.data( "uiDialog" )._title = function(title) {
    title.html( this.options.title );
};

dialog.dialog('option', 'title', '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> Example Dialog');
```

#### For older versions

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> Example Dialog'
});
```

---

And this CSS

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title .ui-icon {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

To add an icon to the title of the dialog. You can see the complete set of jQuery UI icons here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

To see this working, live, see: http://jsfiddle.net/XkSu9/ (jQuery UI 1.10+) or http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/UYMJH/ (old version)

Comment: this does not work in jqueryui-1.10.0. It will escape the html.

Comment: @YoniBaciu This is interesting, because the documentation still says that any valid HTML can be used as the title: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-title. Let me check if this is a bug or if the documentation is outdated

Comment: The change was made here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/7e9060c109b928769a664dbcc2c17bd21231b6f3 to "prevent XSS vulnerability", fixing this bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6016. Unfortunately it seems that the developers failed to update the documentation properly.

Comment: It's working fine with jQueryUI V1.10.2, thank you for providing the insights. **N.B.** You can simplify your life if you're encapsulating the code snippet in a function, as I've shown shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15567411/1016343).

Comment: For jQuery UI 1.10.x, you can apply this behavior globally by overriding `$.ui.dialog.prototype._title` with the answer's function.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by adding some HTML code to title bar when dialog opened.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Dialog Title",
            height: 400,
            width: 500,
            open: function(event, ui){
                $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').append('Some HTML');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you solve the jQuery UI 1.10.0 dialog title issue globally instead of one object at a time:

```
jQuery.widget('ui.dialog', jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype, {
    _title: function(titleBar) {
        titleBar.html(this.options.title || '&#160;');
    }
}));
```

Now use the dialog widget as usual and your titles won't get escaped anymore.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler method. In the stylesheet:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
  background-image: url('/icons/info.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This is for a 16x16 image.

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function MsgBox() {
        var arg = arguments;
        /*
        [arg]
        0 = message
        1 = title
        2 = width
        3 = height
        4 = command to evaluete if Ok is clicked (optional)
        */
        $("body").append("<div id=\"dlgMsg\" title=\"" + arg[1] + "\">" + arg[0] + "</div>");
        $("#dlgMsg").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            bgiframe: true,
            width: arg[2],
            height: arg[3],
            close: function (event, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy").remove(); },
            buttons:{ 
                    'OK': function () { if (arg[4]) eval(arg[4]); $(this).dialog("close"); }
                    }
        });

        $("#dlgMsg").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Usage:
`MsgBox("Hello, I'm a MessageBox!", "Title Here", 400, 200);`

Or

`MsgBox("Hello, I'm a MessageBox!", "Title Here", 400, 200, "alert('hey, you clicked Ok!')");`

You may improve it with ui-icons as well...