# cant access element in dialog title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

I can't seem to get a reference to the on click events of buttons in the titlebar but if they are in the regular content area of the dialog I can click them. Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to register click events from the buttons in the title bar?

```
// Define the player details window dialog
var dialog = $(".graph-container").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function () {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    },
    width: modalWindow.width,
    height: modalWindow.height,
    resizable: false,
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('before close function');
    },
    position: {
        my: 'center',
        at: 'center',
        of: window
    }
});

// Override the undocumented _title property to allow HTML in the title
// More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103964/icons-in-jquery-ui-dialog-title
dialog.data("uiDialog")._title = function (title) {
    title.html(this.options.title);
};
dialog.dialog('option', 'title', '<span class="left">Stats for ' + player.PlayerName + ' - Last ' + $scope.gameFilter + ' games</span>' +
        '<span class="right"><div id="dateButtonDiv">' +
        '<button class="dateButton">5</button>' +
        '<button class="dateButton">25</button>' +
        '<button class="dateButton">100</button>' +
        '</div></span>');

$(".graph-container").dialog("open");

$('.dateButton').click(function () {
    var btn = this;
    console.log('Date button clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your elements are coming dynamically into the dom so the normal click event will not work for them. you have to bind the event on the document object and delegate it to the dynamic class.

following code might work, you can try it in your case

```
$(document).on('click', '.dateButton' , function() {
  var btn = this;
  console.log('Date button clicked');
});
```